# Finding the amount of bits to encode a DNA strand

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

Hey guys I have the following question:

> Suppose we are working with strands of DNA, each strand consisting of
>   a sequence of $10$ nucleotides. Each nucleotide can be any one of four
>   different types: $A$, $G$, $T$ or $C$. How many bits does it take to encode a
>   DNA strand?

Here is my approach to it and I want to know if that is correct.

We have $10$ spots. Each spot can have $4$ different symbols. This means we require $4^{10}$ combinations using our binary digits.

$$4^{10} = 1048576$$

We will then find the $\log$ base $2$ of that.  What do you guys think of my approach?

Comment: It should be $\lceil{\log_2 (4^{10})} \rceil$ because you can't have fractional bits. It doesn't matter in this case because $4^{10} = 2^{20}$, but it's something to watch out for in the future.

Comment: How does that remove the fractional bit? I don't understand.

Comment: It doesn't matter in this example because the number of combinations that you need to represent is a power of 2. But if it was not, then its base-2 logarithm would not be a whole number, and you'd need to round up to the nearest integer.

Comment: Your way is correct.  But recognizing that $2^2=4$ so $2^{20}=4^{10} $ so the answer is 20, should have been much more obvious and easy.  (Or in other words $\log_2 4^{10}=10 \log_2 4 = 2*10=20  $ really should have been  immediate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach makes sense. An alternate approach that gives the same answer:
there are 4 bases, so we need $\log_2 (4) = 2$ bits to encode each base. Each strand has 10 nucleotides, so we need $2 \times 10 = 20$ bits for the whole strand.